# Runtime error 1004 when inserting simple formula with division

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have this small code permitting to fill a table based on data calculated before :

(The last line interest us here)

```vb
'inserts the values calculated
For Each CellCalc In Worksheets(WsPrevData).Range("D" & FirstLine + 2 + NbLinesYear * Counter + 2 * RegionCount - 2 & ":O" & FirstLine + 2 + NbLinesYear * Counter + 2 * RegionCount - 2)
    CountCells = 0
    CellCalc.Select
    For PackOfLines = FirstLine + 2 To FirstLine + 2 + NbLinesYear * Counter - NbLinesYear + 2 * RegionCount - 2 Step NbLinesYear
        If IsNumeric(Range(Split(Cells(1, CellCalc.Column).Address, "$")(1) & PackOfLines).Value) Then
            CellCalc.Value = CellCalc.Value + Range(Split(Cells(1, CellCalc.Column).Address, "$")(1) & PackOfLines).Value
            CountCells = CountCells + 1
        End If
    Next
    pouet = CellCalc.Value
    CellCalc.Formula = "=" & pouet & "/" & CountCells 'Runtime error 1004 here -_-
Next
```

Basically, it just gets the values in different cells in the data already filled, then do an average of these cells and writes it in the last cell.

I'd like to have the division resulting in the value, not a simple plain number.

Therefore, I use the ".formula" and try to insert the formula. This is when I get he following error message:

> Runtime error 1004: application defined or object defined error

`pouet = 120,166907548137` (double)

and `CountCells = 3` (integer)

I tried different things :

- Deleting the "=" sign permits to insert the formula (which becomes useless)
- Inserting directly the result works (but I want the details of the calculation)
- Converting "pouet" to an integer makes it work, but I loose the decimals...
- On the other hand, having both variables as Double don't make it work
- Deleting some digits in the long number changes nothing
- Deleting the Slash does nothing
- Defining CountCells as a double changes nothing
- Using .FormulaR1C1 instead of .Formula changes nothing

Comment: Change `Formula` to `FormulaR1C1` and see what happens

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns Nothing happens... Still the same error :(

Comment: If you want a "simple plain number" with which I assume you mean an integer, use the [int function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions) or the [round function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function)

Comment: @TimStack quote : "I'd like to have the division resulting in the value, not a simple plain number." (Ok, I edited it to make it more understandable ^^)

Comment: @TimStack You mean replacing the "decimal separator" in the number contained in the variable "pouet"? I've never had this issue before... I just tried to convert "pouet" to an integer, and it works... But I need the comma :(

Comment: FYI, your code has a lot of mistakes you'd like to edit. `pouet` is being set in the loop for no apparent reason as it isn't being called anywhere else in the loop, and its value is changed right when the loop exits. Moreover, that first `pouet = ...` could be rewritten as `pouet = Cells(FirstLine + 2 + NbLinesYear * Counter + 2 * RegionCount - 2, CellCalc.Column).Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed `Formula` to `FormulaLocal` and it worked perfect for me

```
Dim pouet As Double
Dim CountCells As Integer

pouet = 120.166907548137

CountCells = 3 

Range("A1").FormulaLocal = "=" & pouet & "/" & CountCells
```

> [Range.FormulaLocal
>   property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulalocal)

In VBA decimal separator is dot, but in some countries (like mine and I guess like yours) decimal separator is the coma. When you use `Formula` or `FormulaR1C1`, VBA is expecting values in English format (and names of formulas must be in english, and arguments are separated by commas, and so on), but if you work with `FormulaLocal` you can use your regional settings.

The code above works perfect for me. Hope this helps

**UPDATE:** Well, another thing that surprisingly worked is:

`Range("A1").Formula = "=" & Replace(pouet, ",", ".") & "/" & CountCells`

Comment: Well, thank's a lot ! I'm still shocked of the fact that Excel generate problems like that... But, does it mean that in a country where the decimals separator is not a comma, it will still work?

Comment: The problem is that you are building a string with a double value holding a dot as decimal point. For example: `Range("A1").Formula = "=10.5/0.5"` will work correctly. As soon as you involve variables, you might run into the issue described here by @FoxFireAndBurnsandBurns.

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure if it would work. Somebody from USA should test the code I've posted and check what happens. I can say that if you use `FormulaLocal` combined with a Function with your language name, it will fail for sure.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns It works, it was simply the "comma - dot" decimal separator problem... What shocks me is the fact that the value in "CellCalc.Value" (also called "pouet") come from calculations made by Excel, I didn't enter values myself... Therefore, Excel generate it's own problems... Anyway, thank's to all of you :)